# PHP:7.4 Non-Static method should not access as Static

Tags: php

Small but strange, why php allowing me to access the non-static method as static. As you can see in my example I just created a simple class and create non-static method and when trying to access the same with scope resolution character, it easily accessible:

```
class test{

    public function myFunction(){
        echo "This is test function";
    }
}

test::myFunction();
```

can anyone tell me where I am wrong in this:

**Output**

[image]

Comment: If you have errors/messages enable, you should be getting something like *Deprecated: Non-static method test::myFunction() should not be called statically in*

Comment: no I already checked this

Comment: Trying your code in something like https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ should show what I would expect.

Comment: check this: https://paiza.io/projects/Qvd8gBOT8u_wgvzMuWtUJw

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start of the script.

Comment: It showing a deprecated error, but in the old PHP version it doesn't allow us to call even

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227104/discussion-between-rahul-sharma-and-nigel-ren).